# How to pass values to WebAPI core methods from Angular UI

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have api method as below

**Scenario 1:**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("CreateRepo/{name}/{location}/{area}/{zone}")]
    public virtual async Task<ActionResult> CreateRepo( string name, string location, string area,  string zone)
    {

    }
```

and calling above api code from angular as below

```
public createRepo(name: any, location: any, 
  area: string, zone: string   ): Observable<any> {  
   
    let header = { headers: new HttpHeaders(
      { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' ,
       'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': '*' ,
       'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*' }
      ) }; 

   let params =  encodeURIComponent(name)+'/'+encodeURIComponent(location)+'/'+encodeURIComponent(area)+'/'+encodeURIComponent(zone);
   let url = this.baseUrl+"/CreateRepo/"+params;
  return this.httpClient.post<any>(url,header );
}
```

Using the above code in both API & angular, I'm able to pass values from UI to API.

**Scenario 2:**

But now my requirement is I want to change route of API as  below.

```
[HttpPost]
    [Route("CreateRepo")]
    public virtual async Task<ActionResult> CreateRepo( string name, string location, string area,  string zone)
    {

    }
```

having just method name as Route. I'm not getting how can I pass angular UI values to this api method.

I tried specifying [FromBody] to params of api method , but didn't worked. From UI, api method always getting null values.

Angular UI code:

```
public createRepo(name: any, location: any, 
  area: string, zone: string   ): Observable<any> {  
   
    let header = { headers: new HttpHeaders(
      { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' ,
       'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': '*' ,
       'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*' }
      ) }; 

   let params =  { name : name, location:location, area:area, zone:zone}
   let url = this.baseUrl+"/CreateRepo/";
  return this.httpClient.post<any>(url, params, header );
}
```

How to fix this?

Comment: you are passing parameters as object so ideally it should be handled using any Model in server side

Answer (score 2):

If you need to pass parameters from URL then you can use

```
[HttpPost("CreateRepo")]
public virtual async Task<ActionResult> CreateRepo([FromRoute]string name, [FromRoute]string location, [FromRoute]string area, [FromRoute]string zone)
{
}
```

and

```
let url = this.baseUrl+"/CreateRepo/"+params;
```

but for `POST` it is recommended to pass data using request body.
Create a new model

```
public class Model
{ 
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Location { get; set; }
   public string Area { get; set; }
   public string Zone{ get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost("CreateRepo")]
public virtual async Task<ActionResult> CreateRepo([FromBody]Model request)
{   
}
```

Angular:

```
 let params =  { name : name, location:location, area:area, zone:zone }
 let url = this.baseUrl + "/CreateRepo";
 return this.httpClient.post<any>(url, params, header);
```

Answer (score 1):

Scenario 2:

```
[HttpPost]
    [Route("CreateRepo")]
    public virtual async Task<ActionResult> CreateRepo( string name, string location, string area,  string zone)
    {

    }
```

The UI Code should be like this (untested):

```
public createRepo(name: any, location: any, area: string, zone: string   ): Observable<any> {  

let header = { headers: new HttpHeaders(
  { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' ,
   'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': '*' ,
   'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*' }
  ) }; 
   let url = this.baseUrl+`/CreateRepo/?name=${name}&location=${location}&zone=${zone}`;
  return this.httpClient.post<any>(url, params, header );
}
```